# How to calculate covariance matrix of data frame

Tags: python, pca, covariance, eigenvalue

I have read data frame of sensor data, using pandas read_fwf function. 
I need to find covariance matrix of read 928991 x 8 matrix. Eventually,
I want to find eigen vectors and eigen values, using principal component analysis algorithm for this covariance matrix.

Comment: There is no function in pandas to calculate the covariance matrix. However, there is a function for a correlation matrix. Perhaps you could use that one?

Comment: There's a difference between covariance matrix and correlation matrix. Though PCA can be done on both. Covariance matrix is used when the variable scales are similar and the correlation matrix is used when variables are on different scales. I would prefer to use covariance matrix in this scenario, as data from 8 sensors are in same scale.

Comment: If you multiply the correlation matrix rowwise and columbwuse by the variances, won't it become a covariance matrix?

Comment: @DYZ Yes, but why not just use `pd.DataFrame.cov`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of this question would be as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig

df_sensor_data = pd.read_csv('HT_Sensor_dataset.dat', delim_whitespace=True)
del df_sensor_data['id']
del df_sensor_data['time']
del df_sensor_data['Temp.']
del df_sensor_data['Humidity']
df = df_sensor_data.notna().astype('float64')
covariance_matrix = df_sensor_data.cov()
print(covariance_matrix)

values, vectors = eig(covariance_matrix)
print(values)
print(vectors)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to put the pandas dataframe to a numpy array by using *df.values*. For example:

```
A = df.values
```

It would be much easy to compute either covariance matrix or PCA after you put your data into a numpy array. For more:

```
# import functions you need to compute covariance matrix from numpy
from numpy import array
from numpy import mean
from numpy import cov
from numpy.linalg import eig

# assume you load your data using pd.read_fwf to variable *df*
df = pd.read_fwf(filepath, widths=col_widths, names=col_names)
#put dataframe values to a numpy array
A = df.values
#check matrix A's shape, it should be (928991, 8)
print(A.shape)
# calculate the mean of each column
M = mean(A.T, axis=1)
print(M)
# center columns by subtracting column means
C = A - M
print(C)
# calculate covariance matrix of centered matrix
V = cov(C.T)
print(V)
# eigendecomposition of covariance matrix
values, vectors = eig(V)
print(vectors)
print(values)
# project data
P = vectors.T.dot(C.T)
print(P.T)
```

Running the example first prints the original matrix, then the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the centered covariance matrix followed finally by the projection of the original matrix. Here is a link you may found useful for your [PCA task](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-principal-component-analysis-scratch-python/).

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. But printing A = df.values consumes huge memory and takes accountable time to print A. It might be because original data frame has 928991 rows.

Comment: If you can't read the file directly to an array, you could also try to use a chunking method to concatenate it chunks from read_fwf to an array using an iterator. like:  'read_fwf(.... , chunksize = 1000000)'

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the `pd.DataFrame.cov` [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html)?

Comment: Hi gmds, The data frame is 928991 x 12 , where 12 columns are id, time, R1, R2 ... R8, temperature, humidity. Covariance matrix needs to be calculated for R1,R2,R3...R8 columns, that is 928991 x 8. Using pd.DataFrame.cov has returned 4 x 4 matrix, with id, time, R1, humidity.

Comment: @Yatshan Are your columns all of numeric type? If they are being omitted, that suggests that they are of `object` type.

Comment: What is meant by object type ? The data I'm talking about is obtained from the following link.https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Gas+sensors+for+home+activity+monitoring

Comment: @Yatshan Check `df.dtypes`.

Comment: It returned the follows`id            int64
time        float64
R1          float64
R2           object
R3           object
R4           object
R5           object
R6           object
R7           object
R8           object
Temp.        object
Humidity    float64
dtype: object`

Comment: Yes, so as I said, your columns are of `object` type. It only makes sense to calculate covariance for numbers. You need to perform a conversion first.

Comment: I converted data with object type float64, using notna().astype('float64'). Then deleted first two columns and the last two columns to obtain 928991 x 8 matrix. I applied pd.DataFrame.cov with modified matrix, it returns 1 x 1 covariance matrix.